# Failing to compile Visual Studio project via the command line. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, cross-compiling

I am not really trying to learn C/C++ but I need to compile the sources for a utility that I will be using with Python.

The installation instructions say that I need to run CMake to build the Visual Studio Project. After I successfully run that I got this output

```
C:/metis-5.1.0\build\Windows>cmake -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Release" ..\..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17134.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24210.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24210.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for execinfo.h
-- Looking for execinfo.h - not found
-- Looking for getline
-- Looking for getline - not found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/metis-5.1.0/build/Windows
```

Since I need to build the above for Python 3.5 x86 I thought that the best option was to use Visual C++ 2015 x86 x64 Cross Build Tools Command Prompt So I opened up that command prompt and I used the following command line to compile the resulting project (created by the above)

```
C:\metis-5.1.0\build\Windows>MSBuild METIS.sln /property:Configuration=Release /property:Platform=x86
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 9/8/2018 8:36:45 PM.
Project "c:\metis-5.1.0\build\Windows\METIS.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
c:\metis-5.1.0\build\Windows\METIS.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solutio
n configuration "Release|x86" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform proper
ties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the defaul
t solution configuration. c:\metis-5.1.0\build\Windows\METIS.sln]
Done Building Project "c:\metis-5.1.0\build\Windows\METIS.sln" (default targets) -- FA
ILED.


Build FAILED.

c:\metis-5.1.0\build\Windows\METIS.sln" (default target) (1) ->
(ValidateSolutionConfiguration target) ->
  c:\metis-5.1.0\build\Windows\METIS.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solut
ion configuration "Release|x86" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform prop
erties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the defa
ult solution configuration. [c:\metis-5.1.0\build\Windows\METIS.sln]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.10
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Update: here are the build instructions

```
The Visual Studio project will be called METIS.sln. Open it in Visual
Studio. If the configuration is not already "Release", set it to
"Release". Type F7 to build. The METIS library will be in
<BINARY_DIR>\libmetis\Release and the executable programs will be in
<BINARY_DIR>\programs\Release. (<BINARY_DIR> will be build\windows if
you used the command line or whatever you choose if using the CMake
GUI.)
```

They are for Visual Studio not for Command Line so I do not know if I have to set the "Release" flag and where ?

Update: changing the command line to
MSBuild METIS.sln /property:Configuration=Release /property:**Platform=Win32** Solved the problem but now I am getting other errors :-(

Comment: Please ask for help from the original developers of the code base. The question in its current status is impossible to be answered.

Comment: I just hope you are not the one who downvoted my question ...not knowing how to work with Visual Studio and with its CLI tools it is normal to ask the question here and blame myself rather than the developer ... voting down in such conditions is.... not saying what it is

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the command line Platform option to Win32